# Updating a module via backend or manually didn't work. No drush available. What else can I try?

Tags: updating, 7

I have to administrate a site I didn't build. An older version (7.x-3.0-beta4) of http://drupal.org/project/context (7.x-3.0-beta6) gives me security alerts and suggests to update immeditaley(!).

The automated update process works fine until it comes to the point where the database should is updated. I just says: No pending updates. Back in the modules overview it still is the old version (7.x-3.0-beta4) and message prompts again: update immediately.

So I tried updating manually. Deleted the context module folder in sites/all/module. And uploaded the freshly unpacked new version (7.x-3.0-beta6). Then I ran updated.php and: same again. Drupal still says old version and tells me to update immediately.

Then I tried to uninstall the complete module through the 'uninstall module' dialogue, though I don't know if uninstalling it completely is a good idea (Is it? Or will data get lost?). But even that didn't work. I deactivated all the three parts of that module (context, context ui, context layouts), then went to the uninstall site but there I wasn't given the chance to check the main part (context).

Even when deleting the whole module folder, the module still appears in every list and the alert message still prompts me to update.

So, what can I do to force the database to update and finally recognize the new files? Or what else would be a point I maybe missed to try?

Comment: Ha, yes, I just was about to comment with that as a suggestion when I read your edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't able to update a certain module, look out for a second maybe renamed folder containing that module. It may then be better to keep the second (renamed) folder and update that one manually, cause that one already is associated to the database.

Comment: or you can do a [registry rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) to get drupal to recognize your new module location.

Answer (score 1):

Have you flushed your caches? Sometimes you will see old data, even in regard to modules because of cache issues.